# Django haystack whoosh super slow

Tags: python, django, profiling, django-haystack, whoosh

I have a simple setup with django-haystack and whoosh engine. A search yielding 19 objects took me 8 seconds. I used the django-debug-toolbar to determine that i had a bunch of repeated queries.

I then updated my search view to prefetch relations, so that duplicate queries would not happen:

```
class MySearchView(SearchView):
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    form_class = SearchForm
    queryset = RelatedSearchQuerySet().load_all().load_all_queryset(
        models.Customer, models.Customer.objects.all().select_related('customer_number').prefetch_related(
            'keywords'
        )
    ).load_all_queryset(
        models.Contact, models.Contact.objects.all().select_related('customer')
    ).load_all_queryset(
        models.Account, models.Account.objects.all().select_related(
            'customer', 'account_number', 'main_contact', 'main_contact__customer'
        )
    ).load_all_queryset(
        models.Invoice, models.Invoice.objects.all().select_related(
            'customer', 'end_customer', 'customer__original', 'end_customer__original', 'quote_number', 'invoice_number'
        )
    ).load_all_queryset(
        models.File, models.File.objects.all().select_related('file_number', 'customer').prefetch_related(
            'keywords'
        )
    ).load_all_queryset(
        models.Import, models.Import.objects.all().select_related('import_number', 'customer').prefetch_related(
            'keywords'
        )
    ).load_all_queryset(
        models.Event, models.Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('customers', 'contracts', 'accounts', 'keywords')
    )
```

But even then, the search still takes 5 seconds. I then used the profiler from `django-debug-toolbar`, which gave me this information:

[image: Django debug toolbar profiler results]

From what I can tell, the issue lies in `haystack/query:779::__getitem__`, which is hit twice, each costing 1.5 seconds. I have glanced through the code in question, but cannot make sense of it. So where do I go from here?

Comment: How many objects are you in your search index?

Comment: @phildini "19 objects"

Comment: It seems like `__getitem__` triggers 2 queries to the database. Take a look on `_fill_cache`, it calls `get_results` twice which takes about 3 seconds overall. Are you sure that all items have been prefetched from the database?

Comment: Previously I also used to build search using whoosh and haystack due to performance issue we moved to elasticsearch (https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)

Comment: I agree with @Taras, Seems like the query is not prefetched.

Comment: Just want to add to @booksapp's comment: If you're working on a production project and considering python+elasticsearch, I'd highly caution against using Haystack in between. Haystack provides a nice abstraction layer, and gets you going quickly, but it makes advanced queries and indexing much more difficult. You'll regret it down the road. Instead look at a first class library like https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py

Answer (score 1):

You say in the question:

> I then updated my search view to prefetch relations […]

The code you present, though, does not use [`QuerySet.prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for most of them. Instead, your sample code uses [`QuerySet.select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for most of them; this does not pre-fetch the objects.

The documentation for each of those methods is extensive and can help to decide which is correct for your case.

In particular, [the `QuerySet.prefetch_related` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) says:

> `select_related` works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the `SELECT` statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, `select_related` is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using `select_related`, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by `select_related`. It also supports prefetching of `GenericRelation` and `GenericForeignKey`, however, it must be restricted to a homogeneous set of results. For example, prefetching objects referenced by a `GenericForeignKey` is only supported if the query is restricted to one `ContentType`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
HAYSTACK_LIMIT_TO_REGISTERED_MODELS = False
```

to your settings.py. As per the docks,

'If your search index is never used for anything other than the models registered with Haystack, you can turn this off and get a small to moderate performance boost.'

It knocked 3-4 seconds off for my project